# JSON AJAX request returns undefined when using square brackets

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm having trouble making an AJAX request with some JSON data that's enclosed in square brackets - the value returns `undefined`.

I've tested a second JSON file that works fine without square brackets but not with them, so I know that's definitely the issue.

The question is where do I make the change: in the JSON or in the AJAX request?

Here's my PHP snippet which creates [this JSON file](http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/shopaholic/rss/asos_f_uk.php?id=1).

```
foreach ($product_urls as $i => $product_url) {
    $result[] = array(
        'product_url' => $product_url,
        'shop_name' => $shop_name,
        'photo_url' => $photo_url[$i],
        'was_price' => $was_price[$i],
        'now_price' => $now_price[$i]
    );
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Here's my AJAX request:

```
$('#container').html('<h3 class="feeds-loader text-muted" style="text-align: center;">Loading...</h3>');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/shopaholic/rss/asos_f_uk.php?id=1',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            $('#container').html('');
            var product_url = result['product_url'];
            var shop_name = result['shop_name'];
            var photo_url = result['photo_url'];
            var was_price = result['was_price'];
            var now_price = result['now_price'];

            alert(product_url);
        },
        error: function() {
           alert("error");
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: What data enclosed in square brackets? Can you give an example of what works and what does not?

Comment: [This](http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/shopaholic/rss/test.php) doesn't work but it does without square brackets. The JSON file linked in the question with square brackets doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach ($product_urls as $i => $product_url) { $result[] =...`

`$result` is an array of rows, so in `success: function(result)` `result` is an array of rows, not a single row.

So this would show a URL

```
var product_url = result[0]['product_url'];
```

I'm guessing you want to iterate them?

```
$('#container').html('');
for (i in result){
        var product_url = result[i]['product_url'];
        var shop_name = result[i]['shop_name'];
        var photo_url = result[i]['photo_url'];
        var was_price = result[i]['was_price'];
        var now_price = result[i]['now_price'];

        alert(product_url);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about try to use this:

```
array_push($result, array(
            'product_url' => $product_url,
            'shop_name' => $shop_name,
            'photo_url' => $photo_url[$i],
            'was_price' => $was_price[$i],
            'now_price' => $now_price[$i]
        ));
```

Instead of $result[]?

Comment: I'm afraid values still return undefined.

Comment: Why should that make a difference? That will result in the exact same data structure.